# Mongoose: How to write find query in nodejs on nested collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to mongodb,mongoose and nodejs. While developing a feature with these technologies, I came across a situation where I have to find collection rows based on child's column value.

This is how "Applications" collection look like.

```
[
{
_id:"",
applicant:"John",
jobID:ObjectId("job_id_1"),
{
_id:"",
applicant:"Tom",
jobID:ObjectId("job_id_2"),
]
```

Applications collection has jobID column. Jobs collection has title.

I want to search all applicants who has applied for job title as "5+ Y Engineer".

I have written my code like as `Applications.find({"jobID.title":"5+ Y Engineer"})`. But this is not returning anything. Am I doing anything incorrect here.

Comment: You will have to write an aggregation pipeline, to join with the jobs first and then perform the search, see $lookup operator in mongodb

Comment: is the relationship defined in the schema

Comment: I am able to achieve this using aggregate with $lookup + $match. $lookup to join tables. $match to filter my criteria. Thanks for highlighting this feature. @CharchitKapoor

Answer (score 0):

```
Applications.find({})
.populate({
    path: 'jobID',
    match: { title: '5+ Y Engineer' }
  })



// Applications where job title is "5+ Y Engineer"
    const filteredApplications = applications.filter(application => application.jobID !== null);
    // Do something with filteredApplications
  });
```

We are using the populate() Method. replace the "jobId" field in each application document with full job document. We are also passing a match option to filter the jon documents. Based on the title Filed.